# Tool displaying processor or core assignment for process in Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

In Windows 7, is there a tool that will allow me to see the cpu/core to which a process has been assigned for a recent timeslice under windows?  I need to demonstrate that a particular application's process's threads can, and do, land on different processors/cores in a multi-processor/core environment with default scheduling behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel VTune for Windows may be what you're looking for.

As for the point you're trying to demonstrate, the answer is almost certainly yes, but it will depend on what else is happening in the system. You can of course take control of which core(s) a thread runs on using the core affinity API routines, but you have to work really hard to beat the OSes own judgement.

Under Solaris there's DTrace, and Linux has a clone called FTrace. I've used FTrace and it does exactly what you want. It might be worth Googling around for an DTrace for Windows. The Windows Performance Toolkit might be just that.

Comment: Thanks, Bazza.  I was able to install an eval copy of VTune, and with minor effort, I got it to show the app visiting two cores simultaneous.  Great answer!

Comment: @cschille, no worries, glad it was useful. Tools like that can make a real difference to multithreaded programming.